# What is the difference between map and apply in scheme?

Tags: scheme

I am trying to learn Scheme and I am having a hard time understanding the difference between `map` and `apply`.

As I understand, `map` applies the function to each element of the list, and `apply` applies something to the arguments of a procedure.

Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

They are not the same! Their names can actually help remember which does what.

`map` will take as argument one procedure and one or more lists.
The procedure will be called once for each position of the lists, using as arguments the list of elements at that position:

```
(map - '(2 3 4))
; => (-2 -3 -4)
```

`map` called `(- 2)`, `(- 3)`, `(- 4)` to build the list.

```
(map + '( 1  2  3)
       '(10 20 30))
; => (11 22 33)
```

`map` called `(+ 1 10)` `(+ 2 20)` `(+ 3 30)` to build the list.

```
(map * '(2 2 -1)
       '(0 3  4)
       '(5 4  2))
; => (0 24 -8)
```

`map` called `(* 2 0 5)` `(* 2 3 4)` `(* -1 4 2)` to build the list.

`map` has that name because it implements a "map" (function) on a set of values (in the lists):

```
(map - '(2 3 4))
 arguments     mapping "-"     result
     2       === (- 2) ===>     -2
     3       === (- 3) ===>     -3
     4       === (- 4) ===>     -4

(map + '( 1  2  3)
       '(10 20 30))
 arguments      mapping "+"      result
    1 10     === (+ 1 10) ===>     11 
    2 20     === (+ 2 20) ===>     22
    3 30     === (+ 3 30) ===>     33
```

`apply` will take *at least two* arguments, the first of them being a procedure and the last a list. It will call the procedure with the following arguments, including those inside the list:

```
(apply + '(2 3 4))
; => 9
```

This is the same as `(+ 2 3 4)`

```
(apply display '("Hello, world!"))
; does not return a value, but prints "Hello, world!"
```

This is the same as `(display "Hello, world!")`.

`apply` is useful when you have arguments as a list,

```
(define arguments '(10 50 100))
(apply + arguments)
```

If you try to rewrite the last line without using `apply`, you'll realize that you need to loop over the list summing each element...

`apply` may also be used with more than those two arguments. The first argument must be a callable object (a procedure or a continuation). The last one must be a list. The others (between the first and the last) are objects of any type. So calling

```
(apply PROC a b c ... y z '(one two ... twenty))
```

is the same as calling

```
(PROC a b c ... y z  one two ... twenty)
```

Here's a concrete example:

```
(apply + 1 -2 3 '(10 20))
; => 32
```

This is the same as `(+ 1 -2 3 10 20)`

`apply` has that name because it allows you to "apply" a procedure to several arguments.

Comment: In Scheme `apply` takes any number of arguments,  but the first need to be something callable (procedure or continuation)  and the last must be a list.  The arguments in between are the first arguments.. `(apply map list '((a b c) (1 2 3))) => ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))`

Comment: Other important difference is that map always returns a list.

Answer (score 7):

No, `apply` calls its first argument as a procedure, with all the rest as its arguments, with the last one -- list -- opened up, i.e. its contents "spliced in":

```
(apply f a b (list c d e)) == (f a b c d e)
```

E.g.:

> `(apply + 1 2 (list 3 4 5))` 
> *;Value: `15`*

It is just *one* call; whereas `map` is indeed calling its first argument for *each* member element of its second argument.

One combined use of `map` and `apply` is the famous `transpose` trick:

> `(apply map list '((1 2 3) (10 20 30)))` 
> *;Value: `((1 10) (2 20) (3 30))`*

Answer (score 1):

As the top answer suggested, `map`

> The procedure will be called once for each position of the lists, using as arguments the list of elements at that position

In contrast, `apply`

```
(apply function argument-list)
```

pass arguments in `argument-list` to `function` all at once. So `function` is called only once.