# Racket: Apply string-replace to list

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

```
 (apply string-replace ";" "" '("a" "b;" "c"))
```

gives me the error message

```
string-replace: arity mismatch;
the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
expected: 3 plus an optional argument with keyword #:all?
given: 5
arguments...:
```

As far as I understand, the problem is that the list is `cons`ed to the arguments of the `string-replace` function, whereas I would like to `apply` the function to every element of the list.

What would be the correct way to `apply` `string-replace` to a list?

```
(apply string-replace "b" "" '("b;"))
```

works, but returns `"b;bb;` whereas I would have expected `"b"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply a function to all the elements of a list, use `map` ([reference](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=map#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29)):

```
(map (lambda (str) (string-replace str ";" ""))
     '("a" "b;" "c"))
```

produces

```
'("a" "b" "c")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! For understanding the answer: Why doesn't something like `(apply + '(1 2 3))` require `map`?

Comment: Because you are applying a function (`+`) that can receive a *list* of arguments (so you could write `(+ 1 2 3)`). In the case of `string-replace`, instead, the function requires only *one* string argument. So if you want to apply it to a list of arguments, the application must be "repeated" for each argument.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I didn't really understand this fundamental concept. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488723/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-apply-in-scheme> explains it in more detail.

Comment: In fact, if you look at the example in the answer, you can see that the function that is applied to a list is not `string-replace`, but rather `(lambda (str) (string-replace str ";" ""))`.